# Override the creation of an HttpResponseMessage for void methods in an ApiController

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I'm building a class that extends `ApiController`, which in turn will be extended by my clients.

In my controller class, I need to change the way the actions' return values are serialized.

For example: by default, the following action:

```
public Person Get() { return new Person(); }
```

Will generate an HTTP response such as:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

{"name":null}
```

If I want to to intercept this `Person` object, I can extend from `MediaTypeFormatter`, and attach it to the controller's `Configuration.Formatters` collection and serialize the object any way I want to.

```
public abstract class MyController : ApiController
{
    protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(controllerContext);

        Configuration.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().ToList()
            .ForEach(f => Configuration.Formatters.Remove(f));

        Configuration.Formatters.Insert(0, new MyPersonFormatter());
    }
```

The action will now be formatted as:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

{"my custom wrapper":{"name":null}}
```

But what if I want to intercept void actions?

By default, void actions will be converted into a 204 No Content response with an empty body. How would I go about inserting data into that response's body?

Note: I would prefer if this could be done from within the controller, so that my abstract controller could do all the plumbing on its own, and not force anything on the clients.

Comment: What version of WebApi are you using? I'm using MVC 5 with WebApi 2 and void methods return `204 No Content`.

Comment: @haim770 I'm using Web Api 2 as well. Yes, I meant 204,my bad! Will update post soon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internally, in the default `HttpActionDescriptor`, the framework is setting the `ResultConverter` of `void` methods to its own `VoidResultConverter` which returns the HTTP 204 with empty content. Also, by referring to it explicitly as `VoidResultConverter` you can't even force it to replace its implementation  using Reflection.

Here's line 34 in [HttpActionDescriptor.cs](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/Controllers/HttpActionDescriptor.cs#L34):

```
private static readonly VoidResultConverter _voidResultConverter = new VoidResultConverter();
```

However, you can replace the `ActionDescriptor` of `void` methods using a custom `ActionFilter` (either globally, in your base controller, or by explicitly defining it on some action using an attribute):

```
public class VoidActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var retType = actionContext.ActionDescriptor.ReturnType;

        if (retType == typeof(void) || retType == null)
        {
            actionContext.ActionDescriptor = new VoidActionDescriptor(actionContext.ActionDescriptor);
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
    }
}
```

And here's `VoidActionDescriptor`, which is actually a wrapper around the regular `ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor`:

```
public class VoidActionDescriptor : HttpActionDescriptor
{
    private readonly HttpActionDescriptor _currentDescriptor;

    public VoidActionDescriptor(HttpActionDescriptor currentDescriptor)
    {
        if (currentDescriptor == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("currentDescriptor");

        this._currentDescriptor = currentDescriptor;
    }

    // this is what we're here for
    public override IActionResultConverter ResultConverter
    {
        get { return new MyVoidResultConverter(); }
    }

    // wrapper methods from now on
    public override Collection<HttpParameterDescriptor> GetParameters()
    {
        return this._currentDescriptor.GetParameters();
    }

    public override Task<object> ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary<string, object> arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return this._currentDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(controllerContext, arguments, cancellationToken);
    }

    public override string ActionName
    {
        get { return this._currentDescriptor.ActionName; }
    }

    public override Type ReturnType
    {
        get { return this._currentDescriptor.ReturnType; }
    }
}
```

The only interesting thing it does is returning our custom `MyVoidResultConverter` in its `ResultConverter` property.

Now the final piece is the actual `IActionResultConverter`:

```
public class MyVoidResultConverter : IActionResultConverter
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Convert(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, object actionResult)
    {
        var res = controllerContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        res.Content = new StringContent("void response");

        return res;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's a very thorough explanation. I was digging into the source code myself but it's no easy task. I'm not at the computer right now, but I'll give this a try tomorrow and let you know.

Comment: This worked perfectly. I ended up deleting my media formatter and using this instead. The formatter was affecting actions that returned either a value (`return model`) or an IHttpActionResult (`return Ok(model)`). By using a filter+action descriptor, I can choose to affect actions that return values, but not actions that return IHttpActionResult, which was my initial goal. Thanks again!